# Gnome3/Archlinux move windows with keys?

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, gnome3, window

Looking for an app that will allow me to move my Gnome3 windows with keys like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> to move to top left corner of the screen.

Essentially, this is what Winsplit revolution does on windows.

Here is one solution, over at ubuntu, but it is a realy PITA:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/84066/is-it-possible-to-place-windows-with-keyboard-shortcuts-in-gnome-shell

Comment: You can look here, maybe that's what you need https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/294/shellshape/

Answer (score 1):

One of the really powerful things about GNOME 3 is the ability to use javascript-based addons to add functionality. Though I am not entirely sure this addon will completely fulfill what you're looking for, I imagine it is about as close as you're going to get.

[Put Windows](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/39/put-windows/) is meant to be a completely customizable implementation of compiz's [put plugin](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Put).

---

*Edit*: I just realized how old this question was. Much has changed since the OP posted the question, but its spirit appears to still be relevant, and this answer should be helpful.